# WPF Compobox - how to display entire content of the two items without scrolling?

Tags: wpf, combobox

The following [Combobox](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/) in `WPF` project needs to always have exactly two `Rectangles` of heights 256 and 36 in each item respectively. And when user clicks on the dropdown button of the `Combobox` I would like to have it display both `ComboboxItems` without user having to scroll.

**Question**: How can we achieve it? Currently it displays only first `ComboboxItem` (Aqua color rectangle inside), and you have to scroll to get to see the second `ComboboxItem` (YellowGreen color rectangle inside). I have tried setting `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` on combo box but that makes it even worst since it does not even allow to show the second item.

**XANL**:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="569.455" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="5" Width="15">
                <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="25">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ComboBoxItem DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <StackPanel Width="180" Height="260">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle" Fill="Aqua" Width="176" Height="256"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ComboBoxItem DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <StackPanel Width="180" Height="38">
                                <TextBlock Text="Second Item:" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="MyOtherRectangle" Fill="YellowGreen" Width="176" Height="36"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Screenshot of the above combobox:

**Display when user first clicks on dropdown of the combobox**:

[image]

**User has to scroll to get to the second item of the combobox**:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce it. When I use your `ComboBox` it shows both rectangles in the drop down..

Comment: @BionicCode yes, i see both items too, but when i add the MaxDropDownHeigth="100" property to the ComboBox, the problem which is happening to post owner is happening in my computer too.Probably it is about default system values.

Comment: @BulutaySaraç [The default value as defined to the property system is a calculated value based on taking a one-third fraction of the system max screen height parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.maxdropdownheight?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8). He should set  `ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight` to `Auto`.

Comment: @BulutaySaraç Very good observation (my upvote for that). In fact, the same code on my other computer, with a bigger monitor, works fine. But your observation has made some users suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dependency property `MaxDropDownHeight` of `ComboBox` as shown below to display both combo box items in the drop down without having to scroll,

```
        <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="25" MaxDropDownHeight="Auto">
```

I have tested your code with 320 `Height` and it works perfectly fine. If you need to add more items, you can increase the `MaxDropDownHeight` value accordingly.

Comment: For only a few `ComboBoxItems` you can set `ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight` to `Auto`.

Comment: @Umar I agree with the comments from user `@BionicCode` that we probably should set the value of your suggested attribute `MaxDropDownHeight` to `auto` because that way you won't have to worry about the increase in the number of items or the increase in the height of the controls inside it. Although, your suggestion worked as well, I would mark it as an `Answer` once you add the suggested edit.

Comment: @BionicCode I agree with your suggestion (my upvote for that). Although the suggestion from user `@Umar` works as well but, in my comments above,  I've asked him to add your suggestion in his `Edit`.

Comment: @BionicCode thanks for the suggestion. That works better. Updated the answer as per your suggestion.